# how to use wait union in c language

Tags: c, linux, posix, ubuntu-18.04

```
union wait wstat;
        pid_t pid;

        while(1)
        {
            pid = wait3(&wstat,WNOHANG,(struct rusage *)NULL);
            if(pid == 0 )
                return;
            else if(pid == -1)
                return;
            else
            {
                fprintf(stderr,"\nProcess with PID : %d exited with return value: %d\n",pid,wstat.w_retcode);
                deleteJob(pid);
            }
        }
```

i am tryng make unix shell where i want to use wait union but i am not able to use it because i am getting error 
 storage size of `wait' isn't known
warning: implicit declaration of function`wait3'

Comment: And what `#include`s did you use?!

Answer (score 1):

You shoud add following include files:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <sys/resource.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
```

See `man wait3`

Here is full example for Ubuntu 18 that compiles without error:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <sys/resource.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

void deleteJob(int pid)
{
        return;
}


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

        int wstat;
        pid_t pid;

        while(1)
        {
            pid = wait3(&wstat,WNOHANG,(struct rusage *)NULL);
            if(pid == 0 )
                return 0;
            else if(pid == -1)
                return -1;
            else
            {
                fprintf(stderr,"\nProcess with PID : %d exited with return value: %d\n",pid,wstat);
                deleteJob(pid);
            }
        }
}
```

On Ubuntu 18:

```
$ gcc -o testwait testwait.c
$ echo $?
0
```

Comment: Put one single #include statement per line as in my answer and in the man page.

Comment: my includes for the program where i want to use wait union but i am not able to use it 
` #include <stddef.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <signal.h>

#include <sys/wait.h> `

Comment: i want to use it on unbuntu what should i do

Comment: I have modified code in my answer: the first parameter of wait3 should be int (and not union wait) according to the wait3 man page.

Comment: In CentOS 7 you can find `union wait` defined in  `/usr/include/bits/waitstatus.h` but I cannot find this in Ubuntu 18 (maybe because Ubuntu 18 is using a Linux kernel 4 whereas CentOS 7 is still  Linux kernel 3). Anyway you should not use wait3 or wait4 but **waitpid** or **waitid** (and if you want to use BSD features you should not use Linux kernel based OS but something like FreeBSD or NetBSD). This explains why I could compile on CentOS 7 but not on Ubuntu 18.